# C# - WinRT - Convert IPv4 address from uint to string?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, ipv4, uint

I have a `IPv4` address provided as a `uint` and I would like to convert it to `string` (for the purpose of logging).

I would normally achieve this in C# using the `System.Net.IPAddress` constructor...but it seems that `System.Net.IPAddress` is not available in C# for `WinRT/Windows` Store. Does anyone have an equivalent way to do this conversion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little "dirty", but seems to work

```
        uint ip = 0xFFDF5F4F;
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ip);
        string res = string.Join(".", bytes.Reverse());
```

Output is 255.223.95.79 for this case

Comment: Works for me - thanks! (except my IP was already in host order so I just removed the reverse())

Comment: Should the same work for IPv6 addresses stored as uint? (if . is changed for :)

Comment: By definition, you can not store Ipv6 address as uint :) unit has only 4 bytes. And I'm not sure it will work even with long or Int64. Ipv6 are not coded the same way

Comment: Lol, sorry my bad...yes, I have the IPv6 address stored in a byte[16]. Usually I would pass that byte array into System.Net.IPAddress constructor. Any tips on how to get that byte array formatted as a IPv6 address string without System.Net.IPAddress ? :)

Comment: You can try the same method, but I really don't know what the result will be :) Take just last line. But I think ipv6 is not formatted byte by byte

Comment: Ok thanks...this doesn't seem to work (as you suspected). This might become my next question on stackoverflow :)